How can I verify user logged in via AWS Amplify & Cognito in backend?
I am currently using AWS Amplify to host a React front-end. I have an AWS Cognito user pool and identity pool set up. Using withAuthenticator from @aws-amplify/ui-react, the front-end requires the user to log in. Once logged in, I can use fetchAuthSession from aws-amplify/auth to retrieve the access token and the identity token, which are both supposed to be JWTs.
My backend is implemented in Flask, and I understand that to verify which user is making a request from the front-end, I should send the identity token and validate it (e.g. using pyjwt). The problem is, the AWS Amplify auth library seems to assume throughout the code that only the payload of the JWTs matters, discarding the header and the signature, which are both necessary for validating a JWT.
Am I going down the wrong path for authentication validation on the back-end? If not, what am I missing about getting access to those headers and signatures?

First, I feel that this should be split into three questions:

Should you use the identity token or the access token? (probably the latter)
Should you indeed send it to the backend and validate it, for authorization?
How do you get the full JWT with Amplify, not just the payload?

Second, here is the answer to the most pressing question, 3.
It is ridiculously simple, but for some reason I could not find this documented anywhere. Just call toString on a token, and you will get the full token, not just the payload.
